# How to fix SMTPNotSupportedError and SMTPAuthenticationError?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to send thousands of emails in python by using an open source SMTP server. I have to locally install an open source SMTP server on windows 10 that can send bulk emails , without any limit.

I have installed HMailServer on my windows 10 & configured it as a localhost, I have set a domain as "st.com" in HmailServer and created a account with that domain as "ammar@st.com". Now I have to send emails to user with that account. The list of Receivers emails are in  .xlsx file (receivers email e.g. is like ammar@gmail.com)

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

SenderAddress = "ammar@st.com"
password = "123456789"

e = pd.read_excel("Email.xlsx")
emails = e['Emails'].values
server = smtplib.SMTP("localhost", 25)
#server.starttls()
#server.login(SenderAddress, password)
msg = "Hello this is a email form python"
subject = "Hello world"
body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject,msg)
for email in emails:
    server.sendmail(SenderAddress, email, body)
    print("Sent")
server.quit()
```

After I run this program it gives "SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server." error and "SMTPAuthenticationError: (530, b'A SSL/TLS-connection is required for authentication.')".
Can anybody tell me how it works that I can send a email to list of users with HmailServer or any other server locally.